# Change row data mySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

EDIT:  I am creating a login and signup for a website. But, I am making it require a activation via email. I want to have them directed to a webpage that changed their "active" status in the database to 1 (boolean) so that they are then permitted to login. All I need now is to be able to change the value in the database

Comment: You need to be way more specific.

Comment: Apologies I am new to PHP and mySQL.  I am creating a login and signup for a website. But, I am making it require a activation via email.  I want to have them directed to a webpage that changed their "active" status in the database to 1 (boolean) so that they are then permitted to login.  All I need now is to be able to change the value in the database

Comment: Are you having trouble in creating the SQL statement (which would be strange to believe, since you've obviously got everything else to work).

Comment: I am having trouble creating a PHP statement to change the value in the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a table activations. When user signs up, create a random hash, and store it in this table along with his new user id. Then send an email, containing an url with the hash (for example, `http://example.com/confirmation.php?hash=376728zhdif274thfj36`).

In your confirmation.php, you'd take the `$_GET` value, query the database with it, and select the according user id, then run another query with the user id, in which you'd set his activation status.

Creating a new hash:

```
INSERT INTO activations (hash, userid) VALUES ($hash, $userid)
```

Selecting the userid with the hash:

```
SELECT userid FROM activations WHERE hash = $_GET['hash']
```

Updating the activation status with the user id from the query above:

```
UPDATE users SET active = 1 WHERE userid = $userid
```